# Change background in Skype "Together mode"

Tags: windows-10, skype, skype-for-windows-10

Today I got to experience the "Together mode" in Skype version 8.67.0.97 in Windows 10.

[image]

While that was very fascinating, I'd like to change the background photo so that it looks like we're all in a different location.

How can that be done?

Comment: Have you tried [Custom Virtual Backgrounds](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-custom-backgrounds-skype-video-calls/)?

Comment: @harrymc yes I'm familiar with the background effects be that "Blur" or any other (including own selected image). That "Together mode" image isn't in that area

Comment: The documentation talks about a "Change scene" button. See [this article](https://office365itpros.com/2020/11/11/microsoft-improves-teams-together-mode-new-scenes/).

Comment: Thank you for the link @harrymc. That is in Microsoft Teams though. You can see in the picture present in the question that there's no such button

Comment: Since this mode crossed over from Teams, it might mean that the feature either didn't make it, or not yet. There is no info about when "Change scene" will arrive in Skype, but it probably will, in time. Note that it only allows stock scenes.

Comment: @harrymc thank you. It doesn't work thaaaat great yet. Some people joined through Android and in order to see this together screen they had to share their screen first

Comment: It's new, so expect some rough spots.

Comment: A year later and it's still a complete catastrophe. If one person turns on together mode by mistake, you have to spend half an hour trying to coach everyone individually into turning it off. The interface is completely different on different devices. It's comprised entirely of visual elements in nonsensical positions that can not be verbally described. UI elements move around, disappear, get covered by other elements, respond to gestures that can easily be unintentionally invoked, go grey and stop working with no explanation, and generally conspire to confuse and frustrate everybody.